# npm ERR! 404 '@reactivex/rxjs' is not in the npm registry

Tags: angularjs, npm, webpack, nexus, artifactory

Issues with installing this package from NPM.  Trying to install since it is a dep of Angular2

Error:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-alpha.6"
npm ERR! node v4.2.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @reactivex/rxjs
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 '@reactivex/rxjs' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue as it turns out is that we are using Artifactory as a private NPM repository.  Artifactory did not support Scopes i.e. @reactivex vs angular. The `@` is the new scoping capability from NPM.  After a little research found the same error with some versions of Sonatype Nexus NPM repositories.

Switched to NPM directly and this solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

@ccit-spence thank you for reporting this issue. Wanted to let you know the issue is resolved in Artifactory 4.3.3. 
You can always grab the latest version from [Bintray](https://bintray.com/jfrog), and this specific version [here](https://bintray.com/jfrog/artifactory-pro/jfrog-artifactory-pro-zip/4.3.3/view).

Comment: Sure, Artifactory Online servers have been updated.
In case you have any further issues please don't hesitate to contact our support team.